# Delta function of a product

Tags: dirac-delta, quantum-field-theory

Manoukian in *QFT I* page 236 writes an equality of the form

$$\delta\left((k^0)^2-|\mathbf{k}|^2\right)=\frac{\delta(k^0-|\mathbf{k}|)+\delta(k^0+|\mathbf{k}|)}{2|\mathbf{k}|}$$

(with $k$ the components of a photon four-momentum) but provides no further explanation.

My approach was with a product $\delta(ab)$, in which working backwards with a limit definition gives 
$$\frac{\epsilon}{\frac{a^2b^2 + \epsilon^4}{a^2+b^2} + \epsilon^2} + \mathcal{O}( \epsilon^2)$$
$$\implies \delta(a)+\delta(b)=\delta\left(\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$$

For the case at hand we are dealing with a photon four-momentum so on shell $(k^0)^2+|\mathbf{k}|^2=0+2|\mathbf{k}|^2$, but this gives

$$\delta\left(\frac{(k^0)^2-|\mathbf{k}|^2}{\sqrt{2}|\mathbf{k}|}\right)=\delta(k^0-|\mathbf{k}|)+\delta(k^0+|\mathbf{k}|)$$

instead. Treating $k$ as a constant my derivation is off by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$.

- How is the identity derived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\int_{\Bbb R}\delta(x)f(x)dx=f(0)$, integration by substitution gives$\int_{\Bbb R}\delta(g(x))f(g(x))g^\prime(x)dx=f(0)$ for injective $g$ of domain and range $\Bbb R$. If instead $g$ has countably many roots, each of them gets a $\delta$-spoke contribution, viz.$$\int_{\Bbb R}\delta(g(x))h(x)dx=\sum_{g(y)=0}\frac{h(y)}{\left|g^\prime(y)\right|}=\sum_{g(x)=0}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\delta(x-y)h(x)dx}{\left|g^\prime(y)\right|}.$$Restating this as a result on measures instead of integrals,$$\delta(g(x))=\sum_{g(y)=0}\frac{\delta(x-y)}{|g^\prime(y)|}.$$You want the special case $x=k^0,\,g(k^0)=\left(k^0\right)^2-|\mathbf{k}|^2$, so $g$ has two roots, $\pm|\mathbf{k}|$.

As an addendum, let's revisit your approach. With $a=k^0-|\mathbf{k}|,\,b=k^0+|\mathbf{k}|$ we get$$\frac{\delta(a)+\delta(b)}{b-a}=\frac{1}{b-a}\delta\left(\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{b-a}\delta\left(ab\right),$$with $k^0=|\mathbf{k}|\implies a=0\implies\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{b-a}=1$ as required.

Comment: Could you explain why the limit derivation is incorrect?

Comment: I know, I was trying to use the limit $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \dfrac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}=\delta (x)$, but evidently when I use other limits I get different expressions...

Comment: @Quantumnness Ah, I understand your reasoning now. I think you just had an arithmetic error near the end. See my edit.

Comment: Why did you set $a=0$? One thing I noticed is that with $a=b$ my equation erroneously implies $2\delta(a)=\sqrt{2}\delta(|a|)$, and it seems to carry over to your addendum if one does not multiply by $(a-b)^{-1}$

Comment: @Quantumness Why would you set $a=b$? That's equivalent to $|\mathbf{k}|=0$. I set $a=0$ because $k^0=|\mathbf{k}|$.